# openERP: How call a "SIMILAR TO" statement on field's domain attribute?

Tags: xml, regex, postgresql, odoo

this field creates a drop down list of accounts that adds the 1xx  series to that list.

```
<field name="account_id" widget="selection"
  domain="[
    '|',
    ('code', 'like', '1__'),
    '&amp;',
    ('user_type.report_type','=','expense'),
    ('type','!=','view'),
    ]"
  />
```

However more types of accounts are needed, like 2xx till 7xx series and strictly no further.  So my question is, how to do this through regular expression?  Here are my test results:

```
# ... WHERE code LIKE '1__'; -- works (1)
# ... WHERE code SIMILAR TO '[1-7]__'; -- works (2)
```

Respectively:

```
('code', 'like', '1__'),  # working (3)
('code', 'similar to', '[1-7]__'),  # NOT working (4)
```

Number (4) throws me this error:

```
('ValidateError', u'Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch:
Invalid XML for View Architecture!')
```

I am also aware that these are prefix notation, but hoppefully we dont go to writing number (3), 7 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'similar to' operator doesn't exist in OpenERP (we should now say Odoo).

To do what you want, you should create a domain with '|' operands and multiple tuples :

```
domain="[
('user_type.report_type','=','expense'),
('type','!=','view'),
'|', '|', '|', '|', '|', '|',
('code', 'like', '1__'),
('code', 'like', '2__'),
('code', 'like', '3__'),
('code', 'like', '4__'),
('code', 'like', '5__'),
('code', 'like', '6__'),
('code', 'like', '7__'),
]"
```